# Defining lexicographic order in an inductive datatype

Tags: dafny

```
datatype T=    C0
             | C1(s:string) 
             | C2(d:T) 
             | C3(d:T) 
             | C4(d1:T,d2:T)
             | C5(d1:T,d2:T)

predicate method leq_string(s1:string,s2:string)
{
s1 == "" || (s2 != "" && s1[0] <= s2[0] && ( s1[0] == s2[0] ==> leq_string(s1[1..],s2[1..])))
}

lemma antisym_leq_string_Lemma (s1:string, s2:string)
ensures (leq_string(s1,s2)  && leq_string(s2,s1) ) ==> s1 == s2
{
if s1 != "" && s2 != "" { antisym_leq_string_Lemma(s1[1..],s2[1..]);}
}

predicate method leq_T (alpha:T, beta:T)
{
alpha == C0
||
(alpha.C1? && beta != C0 && (beta.C1? ==> leq_string(alpha.s,beta.s)))
||
(alpha.C2? && beta != C0 && !beta.C1? && (beta.C2? ==> leq_T(alpha.d,beta.d)))
||
(alpha.C3? && beta != C0 && !beta.C1? && !beta.C2? && (beta.C3? ==> leq_T(alpha.d,beta.d)))
||
(alpha.C4? && beta != C0 && !beta.C1? && !beta.C2?  && !beta.C3? 
           && (beta.C4? ==> (leq_T(alpha.d1,beta.d1) 
                              && (alpha.d1 == beta.d1 ==> leq_T(alpha.d2,beta.d2)))))
||
(alpha.C5? && beta != C0 && !beta.C1? && !beta.C2? && !beta.C3? && !beta.C4?
           && (beta.C5? ==> (leq_T(alpha.d1,beta.d1) 
                              && (alpha.d1 == beta.d1 ==> leq_T(alpha.d2,beta.d2)))))
}

lemma antisym_leq_T_Lemma (alpha:T,beta:T)
ensures (leq_T(alpha,beta)  && leq_T(beta,alpha)) ==> alpha == beta
{
if leq_T(alpha,beta)  && leq_T(beta,alpha) 
    {
    if alpha.C1? { if beta.C1? {antisym_leq_string_Lemma(alpha.s,beta.s); }}
    // Equivalent to:
    /*match alpha
    case C0 => 
    case C1(s) =>  if beta.C1? { antisym_leq_string_Lemma(s,beta.s);}
    case C2(phi) => 
    case C3(phi) => 
    case C4(phi,psi) => 
    case C5(phi,psi) => */
    //All inductive cases are automatically proved
    }
}
```

Two questions:

1.- Is there some better way of defining a lexicographic order on datatype T in Dafny?

2.- I have defined a datatype like T but with many different unary constructors (like C2 and C3) that shares the name of the destructor, and also many binary ones (like C4 and C5) that also shares the names of the two destructors. I have also define the lexicographic order on this type, exactly as above but with all the neccesary cases. Then, in the corresponding proof of antisym_leq_T_Lemma, the match statement (as above, but with much more inductive cases) works perfectly, i.e.  proves automatically all the inductive cases. However the equivalent "if" doesn't work. Moreover, adding "else {}", Dafny complains that this "else" doens'tprove the postcondition. Could you guess what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think your definitions look fine. Because `leq_string` is recursive, it's natural that proofs of its properties would need an inductive lemma like `antisym_leq_string_Lemma`. And since the proof of the `C1`/`C1` case of `antisym_leq_T_Lemma` needs lemma `antisym_leq_string_Lemma`, your proof of `antisym_leq_T_Lemma` is more-or-less as short as you could hope for.

In the longer definition of `T` and the longer antisymmetry proof you're alluding to, Dafny will still try to call the induction hypothesis automatically. That may not always work, so it's possible you'll need to write it explicitly.

There are many ways to express the properties you have defined, and in the end it's probably mostly a matter of taste how you write them. Here is one alternative, where, for the sake of showing some variety, I've tried to include several variations on what you've done.

```
predicate method StringBelow(s: string, t: string) {
  exists n :: 0 <= n <= |s| && n <= |t| && s[..n] == t[..n] && (n < |s| ==> n < |t| && s[n] < t[n])
}

lemma AntisymStringBelow(s: string, t: string)
  requires StringBelow(s, t) && StringBelow(t, s)
  ensures s == t
{
}

function method Family(alpha: T): nat {
  match alpha
  case C0 => 0
  case C1(_) => 1
  case C2(_) => 2
  case C3(_) => 3
  case C4(_, _) => 4
  case C5(_, _) => 5
}

predicate method Below(alpha:T, beta:T)
{
  match (alpha, beta)
  case (C1(a), C1(b)) => StringBelow(a, b)
  case (C2(a), C2(b)) => Below(a, b)
  case (C3(a), C3(b)) => Below(a, b)
  case (C4(a0, a1), C4(b0, b1)) => Below(a0, b0) && (a0 == b0 ==> Below(a1, b1))
  case (C5(a0, a1), C5(b0, b1)) => Below(a0, b0) && (a0 == b0 ==> Below(a1, b1))
  case (_, _) => Family(alpha) <= Family(beta)
}

lemma AntisymBelow(alpha: T, beta: T)
  requires Below(alpha, beta) && Below(beta, alpha)
  ensures alpha == beta
{
  match (alpha, beta)
  case (C1(a), C1(b)) => AntisymStringBelow(a, b);
  case (C2(a), C2(b)) =>
  case (C3(a), C3(b)) =>
  case (C4(a0, a1), C4(b0, b1)) =>
  case (C5(a0, a1), C5(b0, b1)) =>
  case (_, _) =>
}
```

The proof of `AntisymBelow` mimics the cases in the definition of `Below`, which looks nice (I think).

Note that `AntisymStringBelow` is proved automatically and, since `StringBelow` is not recursive, does not need induction. Dafny can do the same proof automatically in the `C1`/`C1` case, so you can delete the call to `AntisymStringBelow` there. In fact, that lets you remove the entire `match` as well:

```
lemma AntisymBelow(alpha: T, beta: T)
  requires Below(alpha, beta) && Below(beta, alpha)
  ensures alpha == beta
{
}
```

Again, if your real situation is more complicated, you may need to fill in some of the proof cases explicitly.

Comment: I like the definition of the order using the function Family is clearer and shorter, thanks for the idea. Btw, predicate Bellow works in Dafny 3.0.0, but in previous releases of Dafny the case (\_,\_) does not work.

Comment: Good to hear it helped. Yes, the `match` statement was enhanced in Dafny 3.0. Cases are now ordered, so this `(_, _)` works as an "else".